R implementation of Bivariate Test by Maronna
Does anyone know an R package that implements the Bivariate Test by Maronna and Yohai, 1978?
Or maybe a derivate like the adaption from Potter, 1981 ?
Or a baysian adaption ?
Was not able to find an approach. But I am not familiar with those tests so maybe there also exist other names for similiar approches.
